# Get value from ng-repeat outside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I got a header bar outside of ng-repeat:

```
<ion-header-bar class="headerView" ng-show="!hideAll">
    <button id="shareImage" class="button button-icon icon ion-share" style="color:#fff" ng-click="shareImageTo({{originalImageSource}})"></button>
    <button class="button button-outline button-light close-btn" ng-click="closeModal()">{{::actionLabel}}</button>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

And a slidebox where images are shown:

```
<ion-slide ng-repeat="single in slides track by $index">

    <div class="item item-image gallery-slide-view">
        <img ng-src="{{single.original}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="originalImageSource" value="{{single.original}}">
    </div>
</ion-slide>
```

`{{single.original}}` is an URL to an image. But this URL is not placed in the input field. It is shown when I´m deleting this ng-model statement.

If a user clicks the button `#shareImage` the `ShareImageTo(URL)` function is executed. But with an undefined value for `{{originalImageSource}}`.

Any thoughts on how i could pass the URL in `{{single.original}}` to this `ShareImageTo()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [$ionicSlideBoxDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/) you can get the current slide index via [currentIndex()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/#currentIndex). That enables you to get the URL by `$scope.slides[$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex()].original` in your `ShareImageTo()`-method like that:

```
$scope.ShareImageTo = function() {
    var URL = $scope.slides[$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex()].original;
    //your logic
};
```

---

Another approach would be to use `ion-slide-box`'s directive `on-slide-changed`.

**Template**:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
    ...
</ion-slide-box>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.slideHasChanged = function(index) {
    $scope.originalImageSource = $scope.slides[index].original;
    //.. some more logic
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score -1):

**Just create a div that wrap around both your navbar and your slidebox, and place your ng-repeat in that div :)**